# How to find out which files have changed using Sbt

Tags: sbt, watch

Sbt can re-run tasks when some of watched files have changed (~task). How to find out which files have changed?

Comment: In the command window it will tell you which files it is recompiling. Is that what you are looking for?  Not certain what the purpose of your question is.

Comment: i have input xml-files for integration testing and i need re-run tests on file-change (and only for changed files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your build.sbt to see what files are watched:

```
watchSources ~= { files =>
  println(files.mkString("\n")+"\n\n\n")
  files//here you can add files or filter out
}
```

It might help you to test specific Test classes: ins sbt (interactice mode):

```
~test-only full.path.test.ClassName
```

To track file changes in general you can use [Java 7 WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) or  [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) for Java 6.

Source: [WatchService for Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968488/watchservice-for-java-6)