# FileHandler Java with Windows

Tags: java, file, ftp

I am trying to write an Application which lists down the files from the server . Now I want to give users to open any file from the list (Windows) with any editor for example a text file and User opens with NotePad++.

Now is there anyway I can know that if user saves the file,if yes, then I would upload the file back to the server.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial about [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) describing the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) which was introduced in Java 7. You can use this service to monitor files and directories:

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                           StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                           StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am limited to use Java 1.6.

Comment: Its quuite an unfortunate that Ican't use that service. Do you have any alternative on your mind ?

Comment: @Makky Then check out this question: [WatchService for Java 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968488/watchservice-for-java-6)

Answer (score 1):

Use File#lastModified() to get the time at which the file was lastly modified.